# How to disable newline and indenting in DOM Transformer?

Tags: java, dom

I am parsing an XML document and serializing it back. I want to preserve the original indentation and newlines as much as possible. I do not wish to pretty print the DOM.

Consider the code below where the original document has a single new line before and after the `<div>` tag and no indentation.

```java
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String xmlIn = "<html>\n<div>Hello World!</div>\n</html>";
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlIn)));
        TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer domTransformer = transfac.newTransformer();

        domTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        domTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

        domTransformer.transform(source, result);
    }
}
```

The expectation is to see this:

```xml
<html>
<div>Hello World!</div>
</html>
```

But, Java 8 is printing:

```xml
<html>

<div>Hello World!</div>

</html>
```

Java 11 is printing:

```xml
<html>
    
    <div>Hello World!</div>
    
</html>
```

As you can see, they are both adding an extra new line. Java 11 has also added indentation.

How can I prevent adding extra new lines and indentations?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the older versions of Java 8 and java 11 when OutputKeys.INDENT="yes" is added to the transformer.

The Workaround solution is to trim all the lines before providing them to the transformer.